# print selectbox with multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, drop-down-menu

i am trying to generate a selectbox:

```
$turn= array(
'attr' => array('nameid' => 'turn',),
'0 - 499',
'500 - 1499',
'1500 - 3499',
'3500 - 12999',
'13000 - 17999',
'18000 - 23999',
'24000 - 40000',
);

function createSelectBox($array) {
    $out = "<select id=" . $array['attr']['nameid'] . " name=" .$array['attr']['nameid']">";
    $out .= "<option class='choose' >Choose...</option>";
        for ($idx = 0; $idx < sizeof($array) - 1; $idx++) {
            $out .= "<option value=" . $array[$idx] . ">" . $array[$idx] . "</option>";
        }
    $out .= '</select>';
    return $out;
}
```

The Problem is, that it will generate the 'value'-attribute in my option-tag like this:

```
 <option value="0" 499>0 - 499</option>
```

the function cant handle the whitescpace in my array.

Comment: Just don't set the value field. If you don't then it uses the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
function createSelectBox($array) {
        $out = '<select id='.$array['attr']['nameid'].' name='.$array['attr']['nameid'].'>';
        $out .= '<option class="choose" >Choose...</option>';
            for ($idx = 0; $idx < sizeof($array) - 1; $idx++) {
                $out .= '<option value="'.$array[$idx].'">' . $array[$idx] . '</option>';
            }
        $out .= '</select>';
        return $out;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your value are strings you are treating them as integers. try it.

```
<?php
    $turn= array(
    'attr' => array('nameid' => 'turn',),
    '0 - 499',
    '500 - 1499',
    '1500 - 3499',
    '3500 - 12999',
    '13000 - 17999',
    '18000 - 23999',
    '24000 - 40000',
    );

    function createSelectBox($array) {
        $out = "<select id=" . $array['attr']['nameid'] . " name=" .$array['attr']['nameid'] . ">";
        $out .= "<option class='choose' >Choose...</option>";
            for ($idx = 0; $idx < sizeof($array) - 1; $idx++) {
                $out .= "<option value='" . $array[$idx] . "'>" . $array[$idx] . "</option>";
            }
        $out .= '</select>';
        return $out;
    }
    echo createSelectBox( $turn );
    ?>
```